# Error in setting Content Security Policy for loading video from another domain

Tags: node.js, html5-video, media, content-security-policy

I am not able to load a video on my site which I am trying to load from Google Cloud:

In my Node.js server, I have the following to redirect the URL, after checking for its match:

```
  if (url == "targetUrl") { //the URL I am trying to match
    res.writeHead(301, {
      Location: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/myCloudFolder/someVideo.mp4'
    }).end();
  }
```

My Content Security Policy for media-src is set in the header as:

```
"media-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com/myCloudFolder  blob:;
```

I get the following errors in the browser's console when the video is loaded:

```
Refused to load media from '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src 'self' <URL>  blob:".

abc.def.com/:1 Refused to load media from 'https://storage.googleapis.com/myCloudFolder/someVideo.mp4' 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"media-src 'self' http://storage.googleapis.com/myCloudFolder  blob:".
```

On the video element itself, the error displayed is:

```
 The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.
```

In the media-src, I tried by dropping the scheme (https://) as well as by using http, but the error persists.

My question is: What should I set the media-src to, to load the video from https://storage.googleapis.com/myCloudFolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content-security policy should be

```
media-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com/myCloudFolder/ blob:
```

The trailing slash after `myCloudFolder` is needed to match all files in that folder. Without the trailing slash only the exact path is matched. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#hosts_values).

Comment: Yes it worked and I am accepting your answer but why is it that I was able to serve JS files when the script-src included a URL without the trailing slash?

Comment: Can you share your `script-src` directive?

Comment: Here it is. Only someFolder is different string but without trailing "/".  "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  storage.googleapis.com/someFolder cdn.jsdelivr.net docs.google.com ajax.googleapis.com cdn.jsdelivr.net cdnjs.cloudflare.com maps.googleapis.com  developers.google.com translate.google.com translate.googleapis.com  translate-pa.googleapis.com; "

Comment: A pure host matches any path on that host. The trailing slash is only needed after a `host/folder` combination.